# Comparing CSV with different structure

Tags: csv, powershell, compare

I'm trying write script for comparing two CSV files with different structure. I have one file named `cisearch.csv` and second file named `export.csv`.

`cisearch.csv`:

```
Name,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5
server1,100,,,,
server2,100,100,,,
server3,100,,,,
server4,100,50,70,80,80
```

`export.csv`:

```
Host;Drive
server1;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive D: Disk Usage
server3;Drive C: Disk Usage
server4;Drive C: Disk Usage
server4;Drive D: Disk Usage
server4;Drive E: Disk Usage
server4;Drive F: Disk Usage
server4;Drive G: Disk Usage
```

From script I need only output where will be only item which are on `cisearch.csv` but not in `export.csv`. For example:

```
server4 Drive F:
server4 Drive G:
```

I know this for Drive C: but not for another...

```
$csvI = Import-Csv c:\workspace\cisearch.csv
foreach($line in $csvI ){
    $hostname = $line.Name
    $cDrive = $line.P1
    $dDrive = $line.P2
    $eDrive = $line.P3
    $fDrive = $line.P4
    $gDrive = $line.P5

    if ($cDrive -gt 0) {
        Select-String -pattern "$hostname;Drive C: Disk Usage" C:\workspace\export.csv | out-null
    } else {
        Write-Host Drive C: on $hostname non exist
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your selection criteria are. The number of drives (assuming that the fields `P1` through `P5` in the first CSV represent drives) is identical in both files, so why would drives F: and G: for server4 have to be listed, but others not?

Comment: cisearch.csv is report from CMDB: P1-P5 are partitions which are added to the server - server1 have only one drive, server2 have two partitions, server3 only one, server4 have 5 partitions. And i need compare this with second file which are report from Nagios, what is monitored. I need find P1-P5 and server name what is not monitored...

Comment: I think, i need: if dDrive is blank - not valid value, continue to eDrive... if dDrive is value greater as 0, try select-string...

Comment: Please explain (*in your question*) how you get from the two input files to the outlined output (otherwise correct your example). It's entirely unclear to me what your criteria are here.

Answer (score -1):

and what about:

```
function compareE {
    if ($eDrive -gt 0 ) {
        Select-String -pattern "$hostname;Drive E: Disk Usage" C:\workspace\NagiosExport.csv 
    }else{
        Write-Host Drive E: on $hostname not monitored 
    }
}

if($eDrive -gt 0) { 
    compareE 
    }
```

Comment: How does that answer your question? If you need to provide additional information/clarification: please edit your question.